# 'Server DNS address could not be found'

Tags: google-chrome, dns, raspberry-pi

I am a complete newbie and have just started using a Raspberry Pi to run the latest version of Home Assistant. I am currently running it in a headless configuration and can connect to `hassio.local:8123` through Chrome on my laptop with no issues. However, when I try to reach the same address on Chrome on my desktop (all devices are connected to the same wireless network) I get a 'server DNS address could not be found' error message. I have tried flushing DNS and manually configuring a DNS server but no luck. I have a disabled network adapter connection called 'Ethernet' that I cannot remove and I wonder if this is somehow causing part of the problem.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Dan, Try to check if there is connectivity to the Raspberry Pi first, by pinging both by name and by IP address, this would give you an idea if the desktop is able to talk to the RP or not. Next is to try using the ipaddress.local , if still no dice, check if the specific port 8123 is blocked on the desktop side.